# kResolutionExactFit policy in cocos2d-x for Multiple screen Resolution

Tags: cocos2d-x, screen-resolution

i have ported my cocos2d game to cocos2d-x in portrait mode , specially for android devices . i want to support my game for almost all android devices , i have used  960*640 resource . I have followed this :

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support.

Now , i am using Design Resolution 960*640 & policy is kResolutionExactFit. i have tested on this Resolutions 480*320,768*1024,800*1280 , 720*1280. 
In all of these Devices ,My all images & background Images Scaled & fit perfectly But i am getting problem with my circled images. They seems like they stretched height-wise means rounded shape looks like oval shaped. I don't understand why Even i am Confused With my KResolutionExactFit Policy . Any Help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: i m going through the same problem :-/

Answer (score 0):

kResolutionExactFit will stretch the image on both axes, so the image looks stretched,

As you have mentioned, the aspect ratio for which you have designed the resources is completely different from the one you are loading it..

If you want the circles to remain circles they should be scaled with the same aspect ratio..

If you are not interested in the theory :P just use one of the below policy,

kResolutionShowAll - Shows the entire stuff, you might have small borders on either side of the screen,

kResolutionNoBorder - if you dont want the border..

I would personally prefer kResolutionShowAll and add a color so that those borders are not seen...

Comment: .As i am reading this question .it says Design Resolution & Resource Resolutions are same : 640*960 . i am also going through same problem . can you please explain this in brief .Because i am also getting problem with my Circled images using kResolutionExactFit policy. please help if possible.

Comment: Hi shaqir shaiyed, design resolution and resource resolution will be the same..
Whenever we specify the design resolution, cocos2d knows the device resolution, so it scales it according to the policy we specify.. 
Say you designed it for 640*960 and open it in a device 720*1280, it scales 640*1.125 and 960* 1.333 to fit them.. Say you have a circle of radius 100px, now the width would become 112.5 pixels and height becomes 133.33 pixles which looks like an ellipse... Just try once with the mentioned policy it will work fine...

Comment: ya you are absolutely right , but if i am going to change my kResolutionExactFit policy then my all other Resources not looking perfect . so , that's why i don't wanted to change my this policy & just want to scale my circled images only..